# Error with installing wine for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine

I tried installing wine but I always face this message:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The output message says "`wine-hq-devel` is already the newest version", so it seems you have Wine installed. The error messages are for the dependencies of `minitube` and are **not** related to Wine.

Answer (score 0):

you can install another way

1.download .deb file using google
[or here]
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

2.after type command
 `dpkg -i filename.deb` replace the filename and type this command

3.if error generated then install with this commnad

```
dpkg -i --force-all filename.deb
```